# User Profile Dashboard Design

Tags: css, html, users, dashboard, profile

I am trying to create a user profile dashboard for an application I am building using CakePHP.

However, I am struggling to wrap my brain around a good layout/design for it. Basically, I am looking to see examples of dashboards around the web that I can generate an idea from.

I have seen Admin Dashboards you can pay for but not User Dashboards, or account pages.

If anyone remembers seeing anything similar on the web, please let me know...

Comment: I think James' comment hits the nail on the head. Given the ubiquitous nature of these dashboards it is important to know what specific info you will be serving up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry I am sure you will find a good layout, you are off to a good start taking the time to find one that works before doing the grunt work of filling it in. A good layout will improve the UX of your product more than anything else.

That being said here is a list of examples:

- [Patternry has a list of Dashboards](http://patternry.com/p=information-dashboard/) (Mint.com, Google, more)
- [Quince also has a nice list](http://quince.infragistics.com/Patterns/Dashboard.aspx)
- [DSI has a good collection of personal dashboards](http://designingsocialinterfaces.com/patterns/Personal_Dashboard)

Good luck, I hope these help you find the layout you need!

Comment: This is the kind of idea, I am looking for. I am better with programming then design and anywhere I can find ideas like the ones you've given is great. If I could buy a template to save me time I would, but I cant find any website that sells them. However, I have gotten some good ideas here that gives me a starting point... thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, the last.fm example you gave is roughly I am looking for. I will change it to fit my needs but that is what I would like to have in my app.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance! For future searching you can use the search term "pattern" to help get different results if "layout" fails.

Answer (score 1):

User profile?  There are any number of them.  Start with LinkedIn.

To make your question more useful, outline the kind of information you want in your dashboard.  You can't begin to make a layout until you have an idea of what information you want to lay out.

Comment: I just wanted a template or example to start with. What I need in my user account/profile page is irrelevant at this time, as I am currently developing my app and there is chance I will be adding way more stuff then the ones I can think of right now. However, I was thinking about a section for user info, another for emails, friends, suggested links, etc. I was just looking for design ideas.. thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: BTW, the last.fm example jonshariat gave is roughly the example I was looking to get. Something similar but in that regards... thanks