# Best practices for designing a finance dashboard

Tags: gui-design, guidelines, dashboard

I'm creating a finance dashboard that allows the user to drilldown further into various kinds of metrics. Does anyone know of any best practices for designing something like this?

I'm also looking for any reference sites that offer more information on implementing the following controls:

- Charts and gauges
- Traffic lights
- Arrows
- Other indicators
- Interactivity for drill down, annotations, actions (e.g., approvals)
- Alerts

**EDIT**
Guys, you can refer [fusioncharts.com](http://fusioncharts.com) for different types of visualization charts...etc. It is great resource.

Comment: There are many similar questions: [Reference books for data visualisation and dashboard design](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5145/reference-books-for-data-visualisation-and-dashboard-design), [User Profile Dashboard Design](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7597/user-profile-dashboard-design), as well as the entire tag [tag:dashboard].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Brian Suda](http://suda.co.uk/) is your man. I really recommend that you get hold of his [excellent book](http://www.fivesimplesteps.com/products/a-practical-guide-to-designing-with-data) and [video workshop](http://www.fivesimplesteps.com/products/visualizing-data) from Five Simple Steps. They are worth every penny. It will cover everything that you are looking for and more besides.

Also, another good reference is [Information is Beautiful](http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/) which is the website for the reference book. This is more of an inspiration reference but will give you some great ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "[Information dashboard design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100167)" by Stephen Few. It's a really good book about this topic, and it's strongly focused on financial dashboards.

Comment: Yes, i bought that book and going though that. Good one to start with. I am referring to Business dashboards - a visual catalog for design and development